# Python Import Class from Module which is a Child of Another Module

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have the following file structure

[image]

In main.py I am attempting to import a class which is located in property.py.

When I try putting the following at the top of main.py

`from B.C.property import Property`

I get:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'B'`

If I instead try

`from ..B.C.property import Property`

I get

`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Any help appreciated!

Comment: How are you *running* the program? It’s just not run from the right working directory/not set up with the correct environment variables to find that other module.

Comment: I am just using VSCode default behaviour to run main.py. So, my local python.exe is just run with the absolute path of main.py, i.e. "C:/Users/../Python39/python.exe C:/Users/.../A/main.py"

Comment: I don’t use VSC, but if you can configure the runner, configure it to set the working directory to the directory *above* both A and B. Alternatively, set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to that directory.

Comment: What folder is your workspace? Is it the folder where A and B are located? Please show the complete folder structure.

Comment: i believe the problem is because main.py is in folder A which also has `__init__.py` making it a package. Move main.py to the base directory, and make A and B subfolders of that directory.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time/14132912#14132912

Comment: You should package your project and use an  editable install for development.

Comment: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Answer (score 0):

You can add the correct path to **PYTHONPATH** using `sys.path.append()`, or add **PYTHONPATH** using `.env` file or configuration in *launch.json*.

- *https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_env*